# Minimum triangle perimeter with vertex on circle perimeter

Tags: geometry

In 2D space we have two points $A$ and $B$ and a circle with center $C$ and radius $r$. Points $A$ and $B$ are outside the circle.

How can we find point $D$ on the perimeter of the circle so as to have the triangle $ABD$ with the minimum perimeter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[link to the figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnYrh.png)

Regard A and B as two focuses of a ellipse and draw an ellipse. According to the property of an ellipse, for each point P on the ellipse we have |AP|+|BP|=2a, which means that the perimeter of the triangle APB is fixed for each P. We gradually increase the size of the ellipse until it is tangent to the circle O at point P', then triangle AP'B has the minimum perimeter.

Comment: But we probably still need to solve the numerical minimization problem of $$\min_{\mbox{s.t.} x_p^2+y_p^2=r^2} \sqrt{(x_p-x_a)^2+(y_p-y_a)^2} + \sqrt{(x_p-x_b)^2+(y_p-y_b)^2}$$.